# Counting and Probability Arrangement Problem

Tags: combinatorics

## Problem:

3. A collection of eight different books consists of two books on artificial intelligence, three books on operating systems, and three books on data structures.

   i)  How many ways can the books arranged on a shelf so that all books on a single subject are together?

   ii) How many ways can the books arranged on a shelf so that the three books on operating    systems are together?

   iii)    How many ways can the books be arranged on a shelf so that the two books on artificial intelligence occur at the right end of the arrangement?

## My Attempt:

Let AI = A, OS = B, DS = C.

Possible Arrangements:

AABBBCCC
AACCCBBB
BBBAACCC
BBBCCCAA
CCCAABBB
CCCBBBAA

Therefore, answer is six for part (i). However, the correct answer is meant to be 432. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Each of the eight books are distinct, even within the same type.  For example, we might have for our books on AI the titles "*An introduction to AI*" and "*Electric sheep and what AI teaches us about dreams.*"  I'll simplify and denote different books using subscripts.  We have the arrangement $A_1A_2B_1B_2B_3C_1C_2C_3$ is a different arrangement than $A_2A_1B_1B_2B_3C_2C_3C_1$.

Comment: Oh... thanks for that info @JMoravitz

Comment: For problem (i) you found that there are $3!=6$ different ways to designate which sections of the shelf should correspond to which subject.  Now, within each designated area, you should decide what order the individual books are placed.  Account for these additional choices and steps in the process in your calculations by applying the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the books should be considered different (even if they are about the same subject). So for part (i) we have $3!$ ways to arrange the subjects, $2!$ to arrange the AI books, $3!$ for OS books, and $3!$ for C books. So the answer should be 
$$3!\cdot 2!\cdot 3!\cdot 3!$$
As regards (ii), we can place the "block" of $3$ books on OS in $(8-3+1)\cdot 3!$ and then we fill the remaining $(8-3)$ places in $(8-3)!$ getting
$$(8-3+1)\cdot 3!\cdot (8-3)!$$
Now are you able to answer to (iii)?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you got the answer? I could not understand how you got the final answer.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Is it clear now?

Comment: Thank you, I understood part (i) now. I did not quite get the (8 - 3 + 1) and (8-3) parts for part (ii).

Comment: $(8 - 3 + 1)=6$ is the number of ways to place a block of $3$ $Xs$ in $8$ places $XXX00000$,  $0XXX0000$, $00XXX0000$, ... $00000XXX$.

Comment: I prefer thinking of (ii) as first arranging the three OS books and then gluing them together (*can be done in $3!$ ways*).  Then arrange the collection of remaining books along with the glued together OS books on the shelf (*as there are five ordinary books and the one glued set of books, we are arranging six objects which can be done in $6!$ ways*).

Comment: @RobertZ Oh, I still did not get what's happening in (8 - 3 + 1). Like, what logic did you apply to come to that

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Placing a block of $X$s of size $k$ in $n$ places can be done in $n-k+1$ ways.

Comment: oh.. so it is .a formula! Thanks @RobertZ

Comment: Now try (iii)? What do you get?

Comment: I got 1440. (8 - 2 + 1)! x 2!

Comment: For some reason, the marking scheme says 4320 for part (ii) do you know why?

Comment: No. Here the block is at the end (you have not to shift it as in (ii)). So $2!\cdot (8-2)!$

Comment: Thank you very much Robert, you helped me a lot~